# How can we compare two different csv files on the bases of 2 column and print the unmatched rows from 2nd csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can we compare two different csv files on the bases of 2 column(1st column from first csv and 2nd column from second csv)   and print the unmatched rows from 2nd csv file using pandas.
ex-
csv1:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

csv2

```
D E F
4 5 3
5 6 7
```

I need to compare column c from csv1 and column f from csv2 and if the rows are not matched then print the whole row including other columns from csv2.
result-

csv2:

```
D E F
5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use '!=' operator and indexing '.loc':

```
>>> df1
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

>>> df2
   D  E  F
0  4  5  3
1  5  6  7

>>> df1['C'] != df2['F']
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

>>> df2.loc[df1['C'] != df2['F']]
   D  E  F
1  5  6  7
```

Note: '.loc' is not mandatory here. You can use `df2[...]` but if you start with Pandas, it's a good practice to use it explicitly.

To know more, read the documentation about ['indexing and selecting data'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)